# Is the noun Bonum, -i simply a substantive of the adjective Bonus, -a -um?

Tags: adjective, derivation, noun

The noun *Bonum* ("a good thing") seems to have taken on a life of its own as a distinct word in Latin usage.

In derivation and meaning, is this simply a neuter substantive of the adjective *Bonus* ("good")?

References to any discussion of this that may appear in the works of recognized Classical or Neoclassical Latin scholars would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

I don't have anything to say about this particular case, but the phenomenon itself is common.
Any adjective can be substantivized.
For example *rubrum* (from *ruber*, "red") can mean "the color red" or "a red thing".
Translating such nouns depends heavily on context.

As with any word, a substantivized adjective can acquire a meaning different from the original literal one.
I do not know if there has been such a development with *bonum*, but *bonum* as a noun meaning "a good thing" is a regular derivation.

Comment: As an interesting aside, the neuter article in Spanish is *only* used for this kind of substantivizing, e.g. *lo bueno*, *lo posible*